# Apache Camel - Setting values inside Processors

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am not sure how many people have had a chance to deal with Camel Processors. So this is my concern:

I am obtaining some information and sending it to the processor. From the processor, it makes a database call via service and inserts a record. I am using a POJO and setting the values in my model in the processor via the exchange object. I am not at all facing any issues but processor is not meant for setting values in a list or any other structure. It should simply do some processing over the exchange object and pass it on primarily due to the fact that there might be a situation where multiple threads could call the same processor.

This is what I would like to know:

1. Is there any other alternative to processors in Camel where I can do this kind setting over the model. Ex: wiretapping, interceptor etc.
2. If not what else could be the approach?

Comment: This sentence is incorrect:  It should simply do some processing over the exchange object and pass it on primarily due to the fact that there might be a situation where multiple threads could call the same processor. Where  did you get this information from?

Comment: I am not sure on your question. But you can create a bean and call a method in that bean and that method can perform that db call you want to .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Processors` are singletons and therefore shouldn't be used to store state of any type...

some options...

- store state information in the `Exchange` properties or Body headers
- replace a `Processor` with a `Bean` where you can manage the scope (prototype, etc)
- use `ThreadLocal` variables for non thread safe references

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I did some research on ThreadLocal but some people say that it wont really help?

Comment: ThreadLocal won't help with request scoped variables (since they are thread scoped), but does help mitigate non-thread safe resources (SimpleDateFormat, etc)